# Does Oracle guarentee that ORA_HASH is used to determine which hash partition a row is inserted, and will this be honored in the future?

Tags: oracle, partitioning, hashing

I use hash partitioning for a few of my very large tables, and occasionally I have a use case where it would be convenient to have a mechanism that would return the partition name that a row would be inserted into, given a partition value.

This blog [here](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2009/11/21/ora_hash-function/) shows that we can use `ORA_HASH` function for this purpose. Incidentally, it appears this page is the only page on the entire internet that explains this.

I've used it successfully and it works in all cases that I have tried. It seems `ORA_HASH` is definitely what Oracle itself uses to pick the hash partition that it inserts data into, and that at least on the current version of Oracle it is safe to use for this use case.

However there is no guarantee in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions136.htm#SQLRF06313) that Oracle even uses it, or will continue to use it in the future. This makes me think that using ORA_HASH in this way is not safe or future proof. What if a DB is upgraded and ORA_HASH no longer behaves this way?

---

For reference, you can use the following SQL to return the hash partition for a given value:

```
SELECT partition_name
FROM all_tab_partitions
WHERE table_name = 'FOO'
    AND partition_position = ORA_HASH('bar', n - 1) + 1
```

Where `'bar'` is the value you wish to analyze, and `n` is the number of partitions in your table. There are some edge cases when the number of partitions is not a power of 2, which is covered in the blog article linked above.

Comment: What will you do with the Partion Name?

Answer (score 1):

If something is undocumented, it can be changed or removed without notice. Think about `WM_CONCAT` in 12c.

Even if something is documented and supported, it may not be future proof, because it may become deprecated, then later desupported. Think about `utl_file_dir`, `Streams` or the future of `DBMS_JOB`.

You worry about things you have no influence on and not even Oracle knows how they will decide.